# Explain mapping between Spark Structured Streaming executors and Kafka partitions

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have deployed a structured stream with 4 workers over a Kafka topic with 4 partitions.

I was assuming that there will be 4 workers deployed for 4 partitions, with a one to one mapping between worker<->partition.

But, thats not the case. All partitions are being served by a same Executor. I confirmed this by checking the thread-id and logs over the executor.

Is there any document which shows the correlation between Kafka partitions and Spark Structured Streams. Also, are there any knobs that we can tweak around.

Answer (score 3):

The correlation is "1:n(executor:partitions)": a Kafka partition can only be consumed by one executor, one executor can consume multiple Kafka partitions.

This is consistent with Spark Streaming.

---

For Structured Streaming, the default model is "micro-batch processing model", the "Continuous Processing model" is still in "Experimental" state.

For the "micro-batch processing model", in "KafkaSource.scala", there is

```scala
 *   - The DF returned is based on [[KafkaSourceRDD]] which is constructed such that the
 *     data from Kafka topic + partition is consistently read by the same executors across
 *     batches, and cached KafkaConsumers in the executors can be reused efficiently. See the
 *     docs on [[KafkaSourceRDD]] for more details.
```

In "KafkaSourceRDD"

```scala
/**
 * An RDD that reads data from Kafka based on offset ranges across multiple partitions.
 * Additionally, it allows preferred locations to be set for each topic + partition, so that
 * the [[KafkaSource]] can ensure the same executor always reads the same topic + partition
 * and cached KafkaConsumers (see [[KafkaDataConsumer]] can be used read data efficiently.
 *
 * ...
 */
private[kafka010] class KafkaSourceRDD(
```

And we know the default location policy is `LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent`.

---

For the "Continuous Processing model",  in "KafkaContinuousReader.scala"

```scala
  override def createUnsafeRowReaderFactories(): ju.List[DataReaderFactory[UnsafeRow]] = {
    ...
    startOffsets.toSeq.map {
      case (topicPartition, start) =>
        KafkaContinuousDataReaderFactory(
          topicPartition, start, kafkaParams, pollTimeoutMs, failOnDataLoss)
          .asInstanceOf[DataReaderFactory[UnsafeRow]]
    }.asJava
  }

/**
 * A data reader factory for continuous Kafka processing. This will be serialized and transformed
 * into a full reader on executors.
 *
 * @param topicPartition The (topic, partition) pair this task is responsible for.
 * ...
 */
case class KafkaContinuousDataReaderFactory(
    topicPartition: TopicPartition,
    startOffset: Long,
    kafkaParams: ju.Map[String, Object],
    pollTimeoutMs: Long,
    failOnDataLoss: Boolean) extends DataReaderFactory[UnsafeRow] {
  override def createDataReader(): KafkaContinuousDataReader = {
    new KafkaContinuousDataReader(
      topicPartition, startOffset, kafkaParams, pollTimeoutMs, failOnDataLoss)
  }
}
```

We can know each `(topic, partition)` will be contained in one factory, and then will be in one executor.

Comment: although it's in the documentation that executors will consume from kafka topic partitions, when I try to read a stream, I found out that the driver is consuming from all the partitions and not the executors

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DirectStream API then the correlation is 1:1(sparkcore:partition). From [spark streaming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html),

> The Spark Streaming integration for Kafka 0.10 is similar in design to
>   the 0.8 Direct Stream approach. It provides simple parallelism, 1:1
>   correspondence between Kafka partitions and Spark partitions, and
>   access to offsets and metadata

Comment: Thanks Vignesh. But, I wish to dig up the Structured Streaming approach. Is that the same with Structured Streaming too?

Comment: The essential difference between structured streaming and older spark streaming is that, you get a DStream in spark streaming and you get a streaming dataframe in structured streaming. The 1:1 parallelism remains same.